# Select a value from a row that is matched to another value in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my issue:

I have the following table (truncated)

```
ID  CustomerNumber      ResellerID
1   12          NULL
2   56          1
```

As part of a Larger query - I'm doing this:

```
select customernumber,
case when ResellerID = id then customernumber end as 'Parent Account'
from table1
```

What I'm wanting to get is for rows with a resellerID, match that to the ID table and output the customernumber so the result would look like this:

```
CustomerNumber Parent Account
12             NULL
56             12
```

And I can't get the query to play nicely - I've tried running an outer left join but I just get NULL values - so I'm missing some syntax and logic somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `SELF JOIN`

Join the same table by making alias with original table's ResellerID column and second table's ID column.

```
select t1.customernumber, t2.customernumber as 'ParentAccount'
from table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.ResellerID  = t2.ID
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that - I see where I went wrong too - I wasn't selecting the right output

Comment: Yes for such problems you need SELF JOIN and you should know whether you need to use LEFT OR RIGHT JOIN along with proper columns to display the output

Answer (score 1):

do self(Left) join

```
select t1.CustomerNumber,t2.CustomerNumber as Parent_Account
from table1 t1 
left join table1 t2
on t1.ResellerID=t2.id

   CustomerNumber   Parent_Account
    12                NULL
    56                12
```

[DEMO IN DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4a7b93a2cf190ab78df36ca680487bbe)